# Oracle Read Table and Conditional

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a database with several tables. I would like to build a query which checks to see if records exist in one table, and based on whether or not records exist either perform or do not perform a conditional upon another. How would I go about building a query such as this?

Comment: "perform a conditional" what?

Comment: A conditional is a conditional no matter what context you use it in: if _________, then ____________.

Comment: Not necessarily, conditional statements in SQL are different to PL/SQL so knowing _exactly_ what you are doing is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not give much detail on the test you need to perform but it looks like you'll need to build a PL/SQL block to achieve your goal.

Something like

```
DECLARE
  pnum_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO pnum_cnt FROM YOUR_TABLE;

  IF (pnum_cnt > 0) THEN
    -- Perform the other test
  END;
END;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for; sorry for any vagueries, I did not want to give a ridiculous query example.

Comment: @user1821973 i'd just add that its best to add `where/and rownum = 1` for these type of tests. It can be significantly more efficient on large tables as it only has to read 1 row v.s. the whole table or index.